# Python Loop: 4 random numbers x 6

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, for-loop, random

I want to have 6 times 4 dices with 6 sides (6 x 4d6) and Ive try to get a loop like:

```
import random

print random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6)
print random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6)
print random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6)
print random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6)
print random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6)
print random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6) code here
```

and I tried to do it like this:

```
import random
import tempfile
roll = 0
rzuty = [] #dicethrows
wynik = [] #result


for x in range(6):
    for y in range(4):
        roll = random.randint(1,6)
        rzuty.append(roll)
    rzuty.sort()
    rzuty.pop(0)

    for z in xrange(len(rzuty)):
        tempfile = rzuty

    wynik.append(tempfile)

    print (roll)
```

and I get only this out:

```
1
3
3
4
6
4

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I tried so many things but I cant find out whats wrong. Im just a beginner.

Comment: What you would like to achieve? Print result like `[[5, 2, 2, 3], [6, 2, 6, 6], [6, 1, 6, 1], [4, 2, 6, 2], [2, 6, 3, 6], [5, 6, 4, 1]]`?

Comment: You need to loop again inside the `for`. One loop for each throw, then another loop for each dice. There's ways of using only 1 (or 0) `for` loops, but for your purposes, I'd focus on learning loops.

Comment: You have a lot of mistakes in this code. You should review the section on lists and loops in whatever tutorial you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a basic learning exercise, lets do a walkthrough of your code:

```
for y in range(4):
    roll = random.randint(1,6)  # Lets say we generated 2,5,3,4
    rzuty.append(roll)
rzuty.sort()
```

This is a good start, `rzuty` now contains 4 random numbers(sorted):

```
rzuty = [2,3,4,5]
```

Now you pop off the last number:

```
rzuty.pop(0)  # Returns 5
```

Now `rzuty` contains `[2,3,4]`.  That's not right, you don't want that `pop` call in there, it will get rid of one of your results.

Now we loop over `rzuty` and set `tempfile` to it:

```
for z in xrange(len(rzuty)):
    tempfile = rzuty
```

This seems redundant, it could be replaced with `tempfile = rzuty` without the `for` loop.

```
wynik.append(tempfile)
print (roll)
```

Now `wynik == [[2,3,4]]` and we print the contents of `roll`, which as we can see from the top of this answer is `4`. **(Note that this is the issue that you've highlighted in your question)**

The final big  problem is that you don't clear `rzuty` after each loop.  This means you'll keep appending rolls, after simply changing your code so that the `print(roll)` line was changed to `print(rzuty)` my final line of output was:

```
[2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

In summary here's a working set of code (Python 2.7):

```
# removed redundant `import tempfile`
import random

roll = 0
rzuty = [] #dicethrows
wynik = [] #result

for x in range(6):
    # clear rzuty so it doesn't get filled with results over time
    rzuty = []
    for y in range(4):
        roll = random.randint(1, 6)
        rzuty.append(roll)
    rzuty.sort()
    # removed pop discarding results and redundant for loop

    # replaced tempfile with rzuty in append
    wynik.append(rzuty)

    # print rzuty instead of last roll
    print rzuty
```

And an example output:

```
[1, 1, 3, 4]
[1, 3, 3, 5]
[1, 2, 5, 6]
[1, 4, 4, 5]
[2, 4, 4, 6]
[1, 1, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score -1):

you only have 2 loops, one nested within another, which only prints out 4*6 = 24 random rolling results.

I'm assuming this only generates 4 dices with 6 sides for 1 time.

to produce 6 times result, simply put your code into another nested loop which loops 6 times.

Comment: "which only prints out 4*6 = 24 random rolling results" - It's one thing to not look carefully at the code, but quite another to not even look at the result of it. OP's code doesn't produce 24 numbers.